# Clean spring batch metadata mongodb

Tags: spring, mongodb, spring-batch, batch-processing, spring-batch-tasklet

I am using [Spring Batch MongoDB API](https://github.com/vfouzdar/springbatch-mongoDao). In order to free up some space in my MongoDB, I decided to clean up the job execution metadata by deleting any data older than two months from the following collections : 
 - JobInstance
 - JobExecution
 - ExecutionContext
 - StepExecution

Is there any way to do this with spring batch, or I should just create a Dao and bulk delete each collection's old data.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there any way to do this with spring batch, or I should just create a Dao and bulk delete each collection's old data.

Spring Batch does not provide that OOTB, so you need to do it yourself (using a Spring Batch job for instance ;-)). I'm not familiar with the MongoDB job repository implementation you shared (collection definition, relations between them, etc), but here are some useful links that might help you:

- https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-batch/issues/1844
- https://github.com/arey/spring-batch-toolkit/blob/master/src/main/java/com/javaetmoi/core/batch/tasklet/RemoveSpringBatchHistoryTasklet.java

Answer (score 1):

You may setup [TTL indexes](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/indexes/#ttl-indexes) for mentioned collections (with mongo Shell).

If you need to free disk space (works only WiredTiger), you may use [compact](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/command/compact/) command (`compact` requires `dbAdmin` privileges) [Dropping collection also reclames space from MongoDB].

With [collStats](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/command/collStats/#dbcmd.collStats) command you can check how many space you can reclame from MongoDB

Comment: I didn't know that TTL Indexes exists in mongodb, thanks. But, it doesn't suit my use case as I already have data in production. I am going to use a spring batch job to clean the metadata.